# The file *.storyboardc was not found

Tags: xcode, widget, ios8, app-store-connect, info.plist

I am trying to submit iOS app with extension, but get a weird error on validation:
[image]

My widget storyboard named Main.storyboard.
Property file looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Currently getting the same error. Ever find a solution?

Comment: Somehow I solved this error. Try to use storyboard without any kind of translations. If it doesn't help, move storyboard file to another folder

Comment: For me it works when I removed the Localization of the Storyboard

Comment: @artsel : What does storyboardc file mean? How is it different from storyboard file?

Comment: @artsel I'm guessing the `c` stands for "compiled". (found this question as I'm currently getting the error: `The document "MainStoryboard.storyboardc" could not be opened. Interface Builder cannot open compiled nibs.`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's a bug. I solved this problem when I moved Main.storyboard (NSExtensionMainStoryboard defined in info.plist) to the subdirectory of extension target. It means that you can't localize main.storyboard, because it will be moved to base directory or specific language directory.

Comment: I hope Apple will fix that soon.

Answer (score 1):

For me quitting Xcode (version 7.1.1) and trying again did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and found the following to work without sacrificing localization.

1) Copy your Main.storyboard from en.lproj to the root directory of your extension

2) Drag into Xcode the copied file among the extension's files and make sure not to check "Copy items if needed"

3) Archive and validate

This gets it passed the validator for now. I have a developer support ticket in with Apple and they are aware of the issue.

UPDATE 10/15/2014: Apple has resolved this issue. Workaround no longer needed

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue caused by using a "/" in the storyboard ID.

Removing this solved it.