# NSINTERNALINCONSISTENCY Exception happening frequently

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

We are developing big application with large set of classes,
 while using some times it gives the crash at different screens,
The same crash is not happening at the same screen again.

The exception i am receiving is NSINTERNALINCONSISTENCY Exception with the reason

> could not load the nib in bundle but we are not using any nib in the project.

Any help would be highly appreciable

[Please find the screenShot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sx4O5.png)

Comment: check the spelling it should be **storyboard** not storyboardc

Comment: already i have checked it in my overall project i did not use the storyboardc

Comment: when i surfed around the net i got to know that it is an default issue in apple http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187413/the-file-storyboardc-was-not-found