# XCode build fails when switching from iphone to pad or vice versa

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoapods, cocoapods-1.0.1

When building and testing in Xcode and running the app on let's say, ipad and then want to switch to iphone, I get the following build errors:

> ld: warning: ignoring file /xxx/Build/Products/Debug-   iphoneos/libCTCheckbox.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (arm64): /xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCTCheckbox.a

for all my pod libraries.

And then:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKObjectMapping", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in MappingGenerator.o
>         objc-class-ref in SyncingManager.o

for a whole bunch of files.

This started happening after I did a Cocoapods upgrade to version 1.0.1 and ran a pod install.

In XCode (version 8.0 ) my build settings for the project, project target and Pods project are set to:

- Architectures: Standard architectures(armv7, arm64)
- Build Active Architectures Only: Debug -> YES, Release -> NO
- Valid Architectures: armv7, armv7s, arm64
- Target Device Family: 1,2
- Library Search Path: $(inherited), "${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries"
- Framework Search Paths: $(inherited)

When I play around with the "Build Active Architectures Only" setting and Clean the Project and restart XCode, eventually the build succeeds again but I haven't found a reliable order of actions that works.  When I want to switch back to ipad the same thing happens again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for the duplicate issue, looks like I solved it by deleting everything in DerivedData, see [CocoaPods libraries errors building for some iOS simulators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990934/cocoapods-libraries-errors-building-for-some-ios-simulators?rq=1)